# Why was my post about ALT-Levels closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Medical Sciences Stack Exchange post: [How can I lower my alanine aminotransferase (ALT) levels?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/how-can-i-lower-my-alanine-aminotransferase-alt-levels)

Why was this closed "as personal medical advice"? It can help anyone taking isotretinoin who pines to lower higher ALT levels.

Answer (score 8):

I closed it because it's clearly a request for personal medical advice. It also asks us to judge your doctor's opinion. It has been the community's consensus since the site was formed that we cannot and must not give personal medical advice. If you search meta for the word "advice" you'll find multiple discussions about this going back years and the reasons for the policy. In a nutshell, it's because we don't have the information necessary to make judgements about personal medical situations. We have no medical history, no physical exam, no test results, and even if someone provides some of that information, we have no way of knowing how accurate the information is. In addition, we have no way of verifying credentials here. Just because someone claims to be a physician doesn't mean it's true. Anybody can claim anything and we have no way of verifying it. There are examples of credible sounding people providing very wrong medical advice here.

So even though your question might help someone else, that's not the criteria. Many personal medical advice questions might help someone else -- or they might mislead someone else who thinks it applies to them when it actually doesn't.

That said, your question could be rewritten into a generic question that might produce the answer you seek. But you would have to remove all personal details and make it about ALT levels, not ***your*** ALT levels. If you edit your question to make it apply to everyone and not just you, it can be reopened if 5 users or a single moderator agree it's no longer a request for personal advice.

Comment: Can you please edit it to generalize it? I can't as you closed it?

Comment: @Antinatalist Sorry, but the system automatically deleted it as an abandoned question because it's been so long. You'll have to post a new question.